# Formatting of pdfptables using itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext to generate pdf files using java.I want to add 2 tables but the tables should be added side by side,that is table 1 should be aligned left and table 2 should aligned right but they should be side by side.Now when i create tables,The 2nd table gets created below the 1st table.How can we set the position of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a PdfPCell can take another PdfPTable as input, you could create a two column table and add your actual tables in either column.

Comment: But then it will still be one table,I want them to be separated by some distance.

Comment: You can use cellpadding to add distance between them. Or perhaps even switch to three column table where your middle column maintains the distance between two tables.